# How To Use Class Method To Calculate Average Of All Values In An Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to create a class that prints out `Student` details and I wish to know how to take an `int` `array` and calculate the average of all their marks.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String course;
    private int[] marks;

    Student (int id, String name, String course, int [] marks) {
    // constructor which creates a student according to the specified parameters
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.course = course;
       this.marks = marks;
    }

    int average () {
    //  calculates and returns the average mark for the student
        return marks / 5; // error: the operator / is undefined for the argument type int[]
    }

    void print () {
    // prints student details
        System.out.println("Student ID: "+id+"\n");
        System.out.println("Student Name: "+name+"\n");
        System.out.println("Course enrolled on: "+course+"\n");
        System.out.println("Student mark: "+marks+"\n"); // This prints a hashcode for some reason
}
```

}

My question, specifically, is how do I return the average of the `int[]` marks in the "int average()" method (without changing the header or parameters in the parenthesis)?

```
public class T3Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1 = new Student(1234, "Joe Bloggs", "Computer Studies", new int[] {67, 55, 78, 72, 50});
    Student s2 = new Student(2341, "Sue White", "Computer Science", new int[] {57, 85, 58, 49, 61});
    Student s3 = new Student(3412, "Ben Black", "Software Engineering", new int[] {71, 45, 66, 70, 51});
    s1.print();
    s2.print();
    s3.print();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use operator with array, thus `marks / 5` is incorrect. You need to do sum of all array items and store it in separate variable and then divide it with `5`(length of array). You may need to be careful about empty or null array.

```
double sum = 0d;
for(int item : marks) {
    sum += item;
}
return sum / marks.length;
```

---

Moreover following statement print string representation of array and not it's content.

```
System.out.println("Student mark: "+marks+"\n");
```

You can use following way to print array,

```
System.out.println("Student mark: "+ Arrays.toString(marks) +"\n");
```

Comment: I watched some vids on Youtube on how to sum all values in an array but how do I pass the total of sum into "int average()" method without adding "int sum" into the parenthesis?

Comment: Yeah, I just had a Homer moment (d'oh). This was explained earlier in my Java book but it completely slipped my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(marks).average().getAsDouble();
```

And you can convert to int (rounded down) with `(int)`

```
(int)Arrays.stream(marks).average().getAsDouble();
```

Comment: AFAIK casting does not round anything, it simply cuts off every digit after the decimal separator - which **happens** to be numerically equal to rounding down ... but these two approaches are not the same algorithms, especially not for floating point numbers ... its like saying that water and coffee are the same fluid just because they both contain / are made of H2O and have very similar properties

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.stream.*;
```

It's in the package java.util.stream

Example:

```
int[] marks = {10,20,30,40,50};
int sum = IntStream.of(marks).sum();
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: why not use [average()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--)?

Answer (score 1):

Since `int[]` is an object and contains an array with your marks, the `/` operator is not defined for this type. You will have to divide the total sum of the marks to their number to find out the average:

```
double average () {
    double markSum = 0;
    double average;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
        markSum = markSum + marks[i];
    }
    average = markSum / marks.length;
    return average;
}
```

Also, please note that usually the correct data type to use here is `double`, because `int` might get you incorrect (rounded) results: in case `marks = [1, 2, 3, 4]` the average is `2.5`, but by using `int average()` you will get `2`.